# Apply function to grouped data counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> new_confirmIOC.groupby(['ErrorCode','ResponseType']).OrderID.count()
ErrorCode  ResponseType        
0          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    80
           TRADE_CONFIRM           31
1          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    80
           TRADE_CONFIRM           31
```

How do I add percentage of total
eg- 80/111, 31/111 for ErrorCode 0 and so on

I tried

```
new_confirmIOC.groupby(['ErrorCode','ResponseType']).OrderID.count().apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```

But it gives me

```
ErrorCode  ResponseType        
0          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    1
           TRADE_CONFIRM           1
1          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    1
           TRADE_CONFIRM           1
Name: OrderID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I wonder if the problem is simply integer division...
Try .apply(lambda x: x / float(x.sum()))

Comment: No I have already tried float

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `groupby` by first level and divide by `sum`:

```
df = new_confirmIOC.groupby(['ErrorCode','ResponseType']).OrderID.count()
df = df.groupby(level='ErrorCode').apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())
print (df)
ErrorCode  ResponseType        
0          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.720721
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.279279
1          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.720721
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.279279
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df.div(df.groupby(level='ErrorCode').transform('sum'))
print (df)
ErrorCode  ResponseType        
0          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.720721
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.279279
1          CANCEL_ORDER_CONFIRM    0.720721
           TRADE_CONFIRM           0.279279
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Thank you [FLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834664/apply-function-to-grouped-data-counts-in-pandas/42835653#comment72780565_42835653) for comment:

The result of `.count` is a Series, so the apply function would operate element by element. (not on the entire column as it would for a pandas DataFrame).

Comment: Probably worth adding why the OP solution didn't work:
The result of .count is a Series, so the apply function would operate element by element. (not on the entire column as it would for a pandas DataFrame).